# Setting properties in chef-client.rb

Tags: chef

I have a use-case where a chef recipe needs to use 'remote_file' to fetch a file on a virtual, and the fetch needs to be do through an HTTP proxy.  This is not working because chef-client doesn't use the system proxy settings ... it gets its proxy settings from the `/etc/chef/chef-client.rb`

So how do I get proxy settings (or settings in general) into the `chef-client.rb` file on a client?

Ideally, I'd like it to happen at client bootstrap time, but I can't see how to do that short of hacking the code.

The other possibility is that I could create a recipe that updates the `chef-client.rb` file.  But that strikes me as a bit dangerous.  And it means that you need to run chef-client twice before it works, assuming that the missing proxy setting in the first run causes the run to ultimately fail.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you looking to have only one remote_file use the HTTP proxy, or is it okay to have all the recipes use that proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fyi: The default config file is `/etc/chef/client.rb`, you would need to pass `-c /etc/chef/chef-client.rb` to use that file.

To set the[Chef configuration settings for http proxy](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings#ChefConfigurationSettings-httpproxy,httpsproxy,noproxy), you can set the proxy to use with `knife bootstrap` with the command-line option `--bootstrap-proxy URL`. Or, you can add this in in your `knife.rb`.

```
knife[:bootstrap_proxy] = "https://proxy.example.com"
```

Replace the "`https://proxy.example.com`" value with your proxy server URL.

This will add the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` lines to the `/etc/chef/client.rb` file automatically. Alternatively, you can create a [customized bootstrap template](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Custom+Knife+Bootstrap+Script) with these configuration values in the client config section. Something like this (modified from ubuntu10.04-gems.erb):

```
(
cat <<'EOP'
http_proxy "http://proxy.example.com" # replace with your URL
<%= config_content %>
EOP
) > /etc/chef/client.rb
```

Comment: Never had a chance... :-D

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question when I try to get a Chef solo run behind firewall work.

The same `http_proxy` settings for chef client `client.rb` can be used in `solo.rb`

So the chef solo run will be like this

solo.rb looks like below

```
cookbook_path File.expand_path("../cookbooks", __FILE__)
json_attribs File.expand_path("../node.json", __FILE__)

# HTTP for environment behind firewall
# http://docs.opscode.com/config.html
# solo.rb and client.rb can use the same http_proxy settings
http_proxy "http://proxy.company.com:3128"
# http_proxy_user "username"
# http_proxy_pass "password"
```

The chef run => chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -l debug`

It works! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue and could not get hints to work properly as it doesn't seem to work in this particular way + lack of documenation samples.

In the end I just opted to edit the `chef-full.erb` which is the bootstrap default template use to generate the `client.rb`

To get the right file run this:

```
$ gem contents chef | grep bootstrap | grep full
/home/henryt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb
```

Then `vim` that `chef-full.erb` file and add `ohai :disabled_plugins` line inside the `client.rb` here document (`cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'`)

```
Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:Passwd]
```

My patch file:

```
--- ~me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb.orig
   2016-07-22 00:53:33.689961205 -0700
+++ ~me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb
2016-07-22 00:44:21.253493396 -0700
@@ -64,6 +64,7 @@

cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content %>
+Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:Passwd]
EOP

cat > /etc/chef/first-boot.json <<'EOP'
```

Now every time I bootstrap a machine the `client.rb` gets generated with that `ohai :disabled_plugins` line and I don't have to have a custom `client.rb` file.